# Fetch data for custom RSS feed node

Tags: javascript

I'm parsing this RSS feed. Each item has this structure:

```
<item>
  <title>...</title>
  <description>...</description>
  <link>...</link>
  <guid>...</guid>
  <pubDate>..</pubDate>
  <jobOffer:companyName xmlns:jobOffer="https://schemas.jobteaser.com/xml/joboffer">
    <![CDATA[Some text]]>
  </jobOffer:companyName>
</item>
```

I'm able to parse the data in each item, except for the custom nodes. How can I get the content of `<jobOffer:companyName>`?

Here's my js:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(str => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
  .then(data => {
    const items = data.querySelectorAll("item");
    let html = ``;
    items.forEach(el => {
      html += `
            <article>
                <div class="company-name">${el.querySelector('jobOffer:companyName')}</div>
            </article>
          `;
    });
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
  });
```

I have tried with:

```
el.querySelector['jobOffer:companyName'];
el.querySelector['jobOffer\\:companyName'];
el.querySelector['<jobOffer:companyName>'];
el.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "companyName");
el.getElementsByTagName('jobOffer:companyName');
```

Nothing seems to work... Anyone with a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` seems to work

```
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((str) => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/xml'))
  .then((data) => {
    const items = data.querySelectorAll('item');
    let html = ``;
    items.forEach((item) => {
      // Get the company name element
      const companyNames = item.getElementsByTagName('jobOffer:companyName');

      for (let i = 0; i < companyNames.length; i++) {
        const companyName = companyNames[i].textContent
          .replaceAll('\n', '')
          .replaceAll('\t', '')
          .trim();
        html += `
          <article>
              <div class="company-name">${companyName}</div>
          </article>
        `;
      }
    });

    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  });
```

[Stackblitz](https://js-fuukjo.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I get the error: `TypeError: el.querySelectorNS is not a function` - what am I missing?

Comment: can you provide the whole rss/sml doc, or a link to it so i can test it a bit? this method is for xml only, not for html. Maybe its encoded as html?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, see simplified example here: https://jsfiddle.net/mc7xrnwg/

Comment: `getByTagName` seems to work fine, check it out, if it works for you too I'll update the answer
https://js-fuukjo.stackblitz.io

Comment: It certainly does. Thank you so much. Please update your answer.